# Selenium Webdriver C# VS: script failing with NoSuchElementException

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to my script and keep getting this error message. I don't know why because my xpath is correct. I even tried to change it around couple of times and still getting the same error message... Does anyone have a solution to this?

> An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='Password']"}
>
> (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
>
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `NoSuchElementException`, There may be following reason :-

- May be when you are going to find element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, So you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible as below :-

  ```
   IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("Password")));
  ```
- May be this element is inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding the element as below :-

  ```
      IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

  wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("frame name or id"));

     IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("Password")));
  ```

Comment: Thank you :) I will try that :)